# Hacer un componente que tenga propiedades extendidas distintas a las que tiene el componente principal en React

Tags: reactjs, botón, function, importación

Estoy creando un botón componente en [react](/questions/tagged/react) y quiero hacer otro botón que herede las propiedades del primero, pero al abrirlo en el navegador me salta un `warning` y no puedo modificarlo pasándole las `props` del botón componente principal.

Os adjunto el código y no se que estoy haciendo mal, soy nuevo en [react](/questions/tagged/react).

```
export const Button = ({ type, onClick, children, className }) => {
    return (
        <button type={type} onClick={onClick} className={className}>
           {children}
        </button>
   );
};

export function ButtonBig({ id, children }) {
    return <Button id={id}>{children}</Button>;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Podrías añadir el texto del `warning` que te arroja el navegador? Por mi experiencia, te falta añadir las `props` declaradas en tu componente `Button`: `type, onClick, className` cuando intentas usar ese componente dentro de `ButtonBig`. Además, `id` no es una propiedad declarada de `Button`.

Comment: gracias por responder,despues intente meter en el [App.jsx] un [button] y dentro el[ButtonBig] y es cuando me saltaba el error.es que vi en un video que le pasaban solo el componente [Button] y le agregaban las nuevas [props],puede ser lo que dices tu que tenga que pasarle las props tambien @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 1):

Tal como te digo en mi comentario, uno de los problemas que tienes al tratar de extender tu componente es que no estás usando correctamente las proopiedades declaradas y tampoco están tomando en cuenta las propiedades adicionales que podrían ser añadidas.

Tu componente `<Button />` recibe las siguientes propiedades: `{ type, onClick, children, className }`, pero parece que no pueda recibir más, o al menos no las declaras en la entrada de la función. Por lo cual cualquier propiedad extendida no será visible para tu componente.

Para resolver esto, debes usar la [sintaxis `spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para aglutinar en una variable todas las propiedades extra que pudieras recibir en tu componente, de esta forma:

```js
function Button({ type, onClick, children, className, ...props }) { ... }
```

De esta forma, cuando devolvemos el componente `<button />` podemos a su vez añadirle todas las propiedades adicionales que hayan sido declaradas para el elemento, usando:

```
<button
  className={className}
  type={type}
  onClick={onClick}
  {...props}>
  {children}
</button>
```

Así, cuando declaras tu componente extendido (`<BigButton />`), el cual recibe solamente una propiedad `id` y el `children`, puedes establecer las propiedades de `<Button />` dentro de tu componente y pasarle tanto `id` y `children` como propiedades extendidas a tu elemento `<Button />`, de la siguiente manera:

```
function BigButton({id, children, ...props}) {
  const className = 'some-class-name';
  const handleClick = () => console.log('Click');
  const type = 'button';
  const bigButtonProps = {
    ...props,
    id,
    type,
    className,
    children,
    onClick: handleClick
  }
  return <Button { ...bigButtonProps } />;
}
```

Como se observa, dentro de mi componente `<BigButton />` estoy creando las propiedades `type`, `className` y `onClick`, y empaqueto todo en un objeto que he llamado `bigButtonProps`, en el cual añado tanto el `id` como el `children` recibidos por parámetros.

Nótese que además dentro de `<BigButton />` he usado también `...props`, y esto es que yo no sé si mi componente `<BigButton />` pueda ser usado o extendido más adelante con más propiedades que nmo están declaradas explícitmanete.

Luego, una cosa que seguramente te llamará la atención es la forma en que utilizo o devuelvo el componente `<Button />` dentro de `<BigButton>`:

```
return <Button { ...bigButtonProps} />;
```

Esto me ahorra el tener que hacer algo como lo que tu intentas aquí:

```
return <Button id={id}>{children}</Button>;
```

Lo cual sería válido, pero sin añadir `children` al objeto `bigButtonProps`, de esta manera:

```
function BigButton({id, children, ...props}) {
  const className = 'some-class-name';
  const handleClick = () => console.log('Click');
  const type = 'button';
  const bigButtonProps = {
    ...props,
    type,
    className,
    onClick: handleClick
  }
  return <Button { ...bigButtonProps } id={id}>{children}</Button>;
}
```

Por último, puedes ver un ejemplo funcional de este comportamiento en el siguiente snippet con React:

```css
.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.big-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- Don't use this in production: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

  function Button({children, onClick, className, type, ...props}) {
      return(
        <button
          type={type}
          onClick={onClick}
          className={className}
          {...props}>
          {children}
        </button>
      );
  }

  function BigButton({id, children, ...props}) {
    const className = 'big-button';
    const handleClick = (e) => console.log(`BigButton clicked`);
    const type = 'button';
    const bigButtonProps = {
      ...props,
      id,
      children,
      className,
      type,
      onClick: handleClick
    }
    return <Button {...bigButtonProps} />;
  }

  function MyApp() {
    const buttonContent = <span>Click Me</span>;
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>
          <Button
            className={'button'}
            type={'button'}
            onClick={() => console.log('Button clicked')}>
            {buttonContent}
          </Button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <BigButton id={'big-button'}>{buttonContent}</BigButton>
        </p>
      </>
    );
  }

  const container = document.getElementById('root');
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
  root.render(<MyApp />);

</script>
```

Comment: muchas Gracias!!entendido,asi aun hago mas reutilizable los botones....muy bien explicado @Mauricio Contreras